# Increase Prices According to Customer Group including Tier Prices

Tags: price, customer, model, tierprice, grouped-products

So magento doesnt support this and its often asked about.

My customer enters all their prices as Trade pricing, but wants anyone with out that type of account ie not in a particular customer group to only see and buy at Retail price.

Trade get 20% off in my example.

I also use tier pricing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick approach to hack it to work, i use grouped & associated simple products so this may not work with configurable ones. But could easily enough be made too.

In this example the Trade group is 4 & the adjustment is /0.8

**in: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php**

**make function getFinalPrice look like this:**

```
    /**
     * Get product final price
     *
     * @param   double $qty
     * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return  double
     */
    public function getFinalPrice($qty=null, $product)
    {
        if (is_null($qty) && !is_null($product->getCalculatedFinalPrice())) {
            return $product->getCalculatedFinalPrice();
        }

//haydent
        $gId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        if($gId != 4 ){
            $product->setPrice($product->getPrice() / 0.8);
        }
//haydent

        $finalPrice = $product->getPrice();
        $finalPrice = $this->_applyTierPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice);
        $finalPrice = $this->_applySpecialPrice($product, $finalPrice);
        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_get_final_price', array('product'=>$product, 'qty' => $qty));

        $finalPrice = $product->getData('final_price');
        $finalPrice = $this->_applyOptionsPrice($product, $qty, $finalPrice);

        return max(0, $finalPrice);
    }
```

**and function getTierPrice look like this:**

```
    /**
     * Get product tier price by qty
     *
     * @param   double $qty
     * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return  double
     */
    public function getTierPrice($qty = null, $product)
    { 
        $allGroups = Mage_Customer_Model_Group::CUST_GROUP_ALL;
        $prices = $product->getData('tier_price');

//haydent   
            $gId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();  
            if($gId != 4 ){  
                foreach($prices as $index => $value){
                   $prices[$index]['price'] = $prices[$index]['price'] / 0.8;
                   $prices[$index]['website_price'] = $prices[$index]['website_price'] / 0.8;                   
                }
            }
//haydent           


        if (is_null($prices)) {
            $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');
            if ($attribute) {
                $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
                $prices = $product->getData('tier_price');
            }
        }

        if (is_null($prices) || !is_array($prices)) {
            if (!is_null($qty)) {
                return $product->getPrice();
            }
            return array(array(
                'price'         => $product->getPrice(),
                'website_price' => $product->getPrice(),
                'price_qty'     => 1,
                'cust_group'    => $allGroups,
            ));
        }

        $custGroup = $this->_getCustomerGroupId($product);
        if ($qty) {
            $prevQty = 1;
            $prevPrice = $product->getPrice();
            $prevGroup = $allGroups;

            foreach ($prices as $price) {
                if ($price['cust_group']!=$custGroup && $price['cust_group']!=$allGroups) {
                    // tier not for current customer group nor is for all groups
                    continue;
                }
                if ($qty < $price['price_qty']) {
                    // tier is higher than product qty
                    continue;
                }
                if ($price['price_qty'] < $prevQty) {
                    // higher tier qty already found
                    continue;
                }
                if ($price['price_qty'] == $prevQty && $prevGroup != $allGroups && $price['cust_group'] == $allGroups) {
                    // found tier qty is same as current tier qty but current tier group is ALL_GROUPS
                    continue;
                }
                if ($price['website_price'] < $prevPrice) {
                    $prevPrice  = $price['website_price'];
                    $prevQty    = $price['price_qty'];
                    $prevGroup  = $price['cust_group'];
                }
            }
            return $prevPrice;
        } else {
            $qtyCache = array();
            foreach ($prices as $i => $price) {
                if ($price['cust_group'] != $custGroup && $price['cust_group'] != $allGroups) {
                    unset($prices[$i]);
                } else if (isset($qtyCache[$price['price_qty']])) {
                    $j = $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']];
                    if ($prices[$j]['website_price'] > $price['website_price']) {
                        unset($prices[$j]);
                        $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']] = $i;
                    } else {
                        unset($prices[$i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    $qtyCache[$price['price_qty']] = $i;
                }
            }
        }

        return ($prices) ? $prices : array();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension to allow merchants to increase prices for specific Customer Groups, using Tiered Prices. You can install it from here: https://github.com/krakencommerce/magento2-module-customer-group-fixed-price